# Can't remove rotation in D3's radial tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this D3 radial tree graph and what I need is the images to not being rotated, but appear straight together it's corresponding blue circle. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/icBjJ) is the code working in Codepen and I copy it here:

```
var radius = 960 / 2;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([360, radius - 120])
  .separation(function (a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function (d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; })

var vis = d3.select('#graph').append('svg:svg')
  .attr('width', radius * 2)
  .attr('height', radius * 2 - 150)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');

d3.json('flare2.json', function (json) {
  var nodes = tree.nodes(json);
  var link = vis.selectAll('path.link')
    .data(tree.links(nodes))
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('d', diagonal);
  var node = vis.selectAll('g.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; });
  node.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 4.5);
  node.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'img/avatar.40.gif')
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('height', 40)
    .attr('x', 10);
  node.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'img/avatar.41.gif')
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('height', 40)
    .attr('x', 50 );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nodes are rotated

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
```

And your images are appended to your nodes

```
node.append('image')
```

So you need to rotate the images back

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (90 - d.x) + ")"; })
```

I'm not sure exactly how you want to position them, but you need to translate them on both `x` and `y`.

See a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qiCeG

Comment: Is it possible to not rotate the nodes instead of reverse-rotating the elements on the nodes? When I try that, my links and nodes go crazy.

Comment: Android, I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Can you post an example or describe in more detail?

Comment: Trying to accomplish the same end-result, without rotating the nodes themselves. Not really a functional issue, just a peeve of mine. Guess I could try specifying the x/y values instead of using rotate. But didn't mean to hijack the thread.